# Probability of correct books ordering

Tags: probability

Suppose I have 10 books in heap and I want to put 6 of them into 
bookshelf. Also each book has a number on the cover (from 1 to 10). How to calculate probability of situation where books with numbers 1,2,3,4 appears on the bookshelf and in the increasing order? (Other 2 of 6 chosen books could be in random order)

There is my attempt to solve it:

Firstly, calculate the probability of the appearance of the right 4 books among the selected 6. This is $$p_1=\frac{6 \choose 2}{10 \choose 6} = \frac{1}{14}$$
Secondly, find probability of situation, when books 1-4 are in increasing order. $$p_2 = \frac{2 \cdot {6 \choose 2}}{6!} = \frac{1}{24}$$
Finally, my answer is $$p_1 \cdot p_2 = \frac{1}{336}$$ 
But in my textbook ansew is $$\frac{1}{36}$$. What is wrong with my solution? Or it is typo in the book?

Comment: I agree with you calculation and I feel it is a typo in the book.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtain the same your result indeed we have

- overall cases $$6!\binom{10}{6}$$
- situations where books with numbers $1,2,3,4$ appears on the bookshelf
  and in the increasing order

$$2! \binom{6}{4}\binom{6}{2}$$

therefore result should be

$$\frac{2!\binom{6}{4}\binom{6}{2}}{6!\binom{10}{6}}=\frac1{336}$$

Comment: @WaveX Thanks! I didn't get that point!

Comment: Your answer is correct, but your calculation does not make sense.  Why do you have two factors of $\binom{10}{6}$ in the denominator?  Why do you have a factor of $\binom{10}{4}$ in the numerator?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It is a simple direct counting. For example in the denominator we need to choose 6 books among ten, then we need to choose 6 location among ten and we can permutate their position.

Comment: Only six books are placed on the shelf, so there are only six locations.  That eliminates the two (equal) factors I questioned you about.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig We need to choose 6 books among 10 but also their 6 locations among 10 places.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Please, let me know if now the derivation I've carried out is clear.

Comment: Since we are only placing six books on the shelf, I get $$\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{4}2!}{\binom{10}{6}6!} = \frac{1}{336}$$ In the denominator, choose which six books are placed on the shelf, then arrange them.  In the numerator, select all four of the books numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 and two of the other six books.  Choose four of the six positions on the shelf for the books numbered 1, 2, 3, 4.  There is only one way to arrange them in those positions so that they appear in increasing order.  The remaining two books can be arranged in $2!$  ways in the remaining positions.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ah ok, I was assuming 10 different position in the bookshelf!